# htaccess redirect query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect a specific query to another URL in htaccess? The URL is:

http://miniwars.co.uk/player-search?location=&distance_max=&category%5B%5D=epic

The location, distance_max and category are always present, and I only want to redirect when location, distance_max are empty, and category is "epic".

I want to redirect to:

http://miniwars.co.uk/epic-players

The htaccess rule I'm trying is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(category=epic|location=|distance_max=)($|&) 
RewriteRule ^player-search$ miniwars.co.uk/epic-players/ [L,R=301]
```

...But it's not doing anything. Can someone let me know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: For starters, your initial URL does not have a slash after `player-search`, so demanding one in your pattern will make it not even match what was requested …

Comment: Ok, updated htaccess (and updated my question) but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try it like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(location=&distance_max=&category=epic)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^player-search /epic-players/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to redirect when location, distance_max are empty, and category is "epic".

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)distance_max=(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)category=epic(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^player-search/?$ /epic-players/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

- This will allow your query parameters in **any order**
- `?` in the target URI will strip off previous query string